# How to call a variable inside an AMPscript block?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have to call the variable `@xyz` inside an AMPScript block and it throws errors when I try to call it like `%%=v(@xyz)=%%` This is something I need almost on a daily basis and I still couldn't find something to work for me. How do you do this?

e.g.

```
%%[

Var @abc, @xyz, @123

Set @abc = [ABC]
Set @xyz = [XYZ]

IF @abc == 'y' THEN
  Set @123 = 'This is variable %%=v(@xyz)=%%'
ENDIF

]%%
```

Comment: Concat won't work in my case since I have to add entire tables and not just words.

Comment: You can add html to your string. Using the example above - SET @123 = CONCAT("This is variable: <table><tr><td>",@xyz,"</td></tr></table>")

Comment: Why are you setting @123? That doesn't actually make sense to me.

Comment: it's because I'm calling @123 somewhere in the body of the email.

Comment: I think something maybe over complicated here, but to clarify, you want to set (@)123  to render (@)xyz somewhere in the email, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?

```
%%[

    Var @abc, @xyz

    Set @abc = [ABC]
    Set @xyz = [XYZ]

    IF @abc == "y" THEN 
]%%
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>This is variable %%=v(@xyz)=%%</td>
    </tr>
</table>
%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

I have some other examples [**on my blog**](http://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/) that are specific for iterating through result-sets, but you may find some of the conditional structures helpful.

EDIT:

An example with `@123`

```
%%[

    Var @abc, @xyz, @123

    Set @abc = [ABC]
    Set @xyz = [XYZ]
    Set @123 = ""

    IF @abc == "y" THEN 
       set @123 = concat("This is variable: ",@xyz)
]%%
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>%%=v(@123)=%%</td>
    </tr>
</table>
%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

Comment: Thanks Adam but how do you assign the value to @123 ?

Comment: Updated my example above.

Comment: Also, I don't think you can have an AMPScript variable that starts with a number.  I may be wrong in that -- regardless, it's not a good practice.

Comment: Variable names must begin with the @ symbol and be followed by at least one other letter, number, or underscore.

Comment: you can start a variable with _ e.g. _123

Answer (score 0):

You have already opened up the AMPScript block `%%[` `]%%` so you can't use `%%==%%` inside it.

If you wish to output the variable inside the AMPScript block, use the `Output()` function (`%%=v()=%%` is used for *inline* output).

If you want to set a variable to a string and a variable together, use `Concat()`:

`Set @123 == Concat('This is variable ', @xyz)`

Comment: As Alex mentioned, Function calls within an AMPscript block should not include the opening (%%=) and closing (=%%) delimiters.  Info on this is found below:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys but the Output(@xyz) function is printing "Output(@xyz)' instead of the value of @xyz. I also tried calling it simple as @xyz and again, is printing "@xyz" instead of the value. Do I do anything wrong? Thanks for helping :) Vic

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AttributeValue(@xyz)
```

https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/attributevalue/#attributevalue

Answer (score 0):

```
%%[
OutputLine(V('Print Testing in progress'))
]%%

%%[var @test
SET @test = "Success!!!"
OutputLine(V(@test))
]%%
```

Ref: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/output.htm

Comment: please include the essentials of the link, not just the link (such as why the code you provided works)